# Eliminar filas duplicadas según una columna y quedarme con la suma de los valores de otra columna Dataframe Python

Tags: python, dataframe

importaré un excel que convertiré a DataFrame y lo que necesito es eliminar las filas repetidas en la columna Código y en la columna Longitud obtener la suma de todas las filas que tenían el mismo valor.

[image: Excel que importaré]

Por tanto en este caso el resultado obtenido debería ser dos filas, una con el código sombreado en amarillo y otra con el código sombreado en violeta y en la columna Longitud obtener la suma de los 5 registros amarillos y en la siguiente la suma de los 4 registros Longitud violetas.

Un saludo y muchas gracias

Comment: Bienvenido a SOes, por favor realiza el [tour] para que conozcas mejor el funcionamiento del sitio. Has intentado algo?

Answer (score 3):

Lo que buscas es simplemente [`pandas.DataFrame.groupby.agg()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.aggregate.html) (o `pandas.DataFrame.groupby.aggregate()`, `agg` es solo un alias), usando la función suma como método de agregación:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"Código": (3243565654, 23423423, 3243565654, 23423423, 3243565654,
                              3243565654, 3243565654, 23423423, 23423423),
                  "Longitud": (34, 324, 45, 346, 35, 7356, 2456, 2346, 5474),
                  "Masa": (45, 62, 587, 52, 14, 35, 45, 78, 31)
                  })
```

> ```
> >>> df
>
>        Código  Longitud  Masa
> 0  3243565654        34    45
> 1    23423423       324    62
> 2  3243565654        45   587
> 3    23423423       346    52
> 4  3243565654        35    14
> 5  3243565654      7356    35
> 6  3243565654      2456    45
> 7    23423423      2346    78
> 8    23423423      5474    31
> ```

```
res = df.groupby("Código").agg(sum)
res.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

> ```
> >>> res
>
>        Código  Longitud  Masa
> 0    23423423      8490   223
> 1  3243565654      9926   726
> ```

Si tienes más columnas y quieres usar funciones distintas para llevar a cabo su agregación, simplemente pasa un diccionario con las columnas a agregar como clave y como valores la función a usar para esa columna:

```
res = df.groupby("Código").agg({"Longitud": sum, "Masa": "mean"})
res.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

> ```
> >>> res
>
>        Código  Longitud     Masa
> 0    23423423      8490    55.75
> 1  3243565654      9926   145.20
> ```